# How to live update jqPlot graph with ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, jqplot

I know how to update and redraw a jqPlot object *without* using ember...

I created the following fiddle to show the "problem": http://jsfiddle.net/QNGWU/

Here, the function `load()` of `App.graphStateController` is called every second and updates the series data in the controller's content.

First problem: The updates of the series seem not to propagate to the view.

Second problem: Even if they would, where can i place a call to update the plot (i.e. `plotObj.drawSeries()`)?

I already tried to register an observer in the view's `didInsertElement` function:

```
didInsertElement : function() {
  var me = this;
  me._super();
  me.plotObj = $.jqplot('theegraph', this.series, this.options);
  me.plotObj.draw();
  me.addObserver('series', me.seriesChanged);    
},
seriesChanged: function() {
  var me = this;
  if (me.plotObj != null) {
    me.plotObj.drawSeries({});
  }
}
```

But that didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, figured it out, see [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QNGWU/39).

The secret sauce was to update the whole `graphState` object (not just it's properties) in `App.graphStateController`:

```
var newState = App.GraphState.create();
newState.set('series', series);
me.set('content', newState);
```

And then attach an observer to it in the `App.graphStateView`:

```
updateGraph : function() {
  [...]
}.observes('graphState')
```

The `updateGraph` function then isn't pretty, since jqPlot's data series are stored as [x,y] pairs.

The whole problem, i guess, was that the properties `series` and `options` in the `App.graphState` object itself are not derived from `Ember.object` and therefore no events are fired for them. Another solution may be to change that to `Ember.objects`, too.